# Is it possible to implement the highlight function in Forge Viewer by receiving a specific ID from an external web page?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge

IFC format project is being viewed with Forge Viewer. IFC project elements (top panel, slab, right wall, etc.) are listed on an external web page, and I want to implement a function that highlights in Forge Viewer when one of them is selected.

Should I use 'GLOBALID' to implement the function?
I've been looking for Forge Viewer's API(v7), but I'm curious if it provides the same functionality as above.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's possible. Here is a sample demonstrating this idea:

https://github.com/yiskang/forge-viewer-iframe-interoperability

This sample supports two ways to locate objects:

1. By passing querying strings to viewer page's URL (See [public/extlink.html](https://github.com/yiskang/forge-viewer-iframe-interoperability/blob/main/public/extlink.html)):

   - **urn**: It stands for which model to load by the Forge Viewer.
   - **idType**: It stands for the IFC guid type. If the IFC model is translated by the legacy IFC pipeline, then the **idType** is `GLOBALID`. On the contrary, if you're using modern pipeline, the **idType** is `IfcGuid`.
   - **guid**: It stands for the IFC guid of the object you want to locate.

   With those parameters, you can locate objects after model is loading completely immediately by passing them to the URL like the below:

```html
http://localhost:3000/viewer/?urn=dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3bGt3ZWo3eHBiZ3A2M3g0aGwzMzV5Nm0yNm9ha2dnb2YvcmFjX2Jhc2ljX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0X2xlZ2FjeS5pZmM&type=GLOBALID&guid=2cgXCjpDT0ZxBvxMSr3pfm
```

2. By triggering `LOCATE_ELEMENT_EVENT` (See [public/index.html](https://github.com/yiskang/forge-viewer-iframe-interoperability/blob/main/public/index.html)):

```js
// Trigger event from iframe's parent page
const guid = event.target.getAttribute('data-guid');
const idType = event.target.getAttribute('data-idType');

if (!idType || !guid) return;

const iframeWind = viewerIframe.contentWindow;
iframeWind.NOP_VIEWER.fireEvent({
    type: iframeWind.Autodesk.ADN.ElementLocator.Event.LOCATE_ELEMENT_EVENT,
    idType,
    guid
});
```